# Google Cloud Shell or Cloud SQL issue with postgres error permission denied for table Asked yesterday

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-iam, google-cloud-shell

I'm connecting to my Cloud SQL instance/postgres db using Cloud Shell and using my CLOUD SQL User account but getting "*error permission denied for tabl*e" when trying to perform **SELECT**.

I'm not sure if my issue is my IAM GCP account access or my Cloud SQL User account.  My Cloud SQL User account has ***cloudsqlsuperuser*** root access.

When connecting to a postgres database using Cloud Shell, is the IAM account roles used as well or just the Cloud SQL User account permissions?

If I need to update roles/permissions to either account so I can do a query (SElECT) which account do I need to update and what roles/permissions; IAM or SQL User?

Comment: You must connect with the user that owns the table and `GRANT` the `SELECT` privilege to the other user.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that when you navigate to `Cloud SQL > Users` (url: `https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances/<instance-name>/users`) you have multiple users listed there, at least one named `postgres` and the current username you're trying to use.

What happens is that when you create a new user, even though it's granted the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role, that does not mean it has `SELECT` access to already existing databases. [You can read more about it here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-users#creating).

In order to give the current user access to that specific database, first log in with your `postgres` user in Cloud Shell (replace `<instance-name>` with the project instance name and `<database-name>` with the name of the database from Cloud SQL that you're using):

```
gcloud sql connect <instance-name> --user=postgres -d=<database-name>
```

Now in the new **psql** session open as `postgres`, run the `GRANT` command (replace `<table-name>` with the name of the table you intend to grant access to and replace `<username>` with the name of the original user you wish to grant access to):

```
GRANT SELECT ON "<table-name>" to "<username>";
```

When both steps are successful you should be able to close and open Cloud Shell again, login with your intended user and run the `SELECT` query.